# How to use jquery datatable custom button to export crystal report pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, crystal-reports

Exporting Crystal Reports to PDF is working fine if that is done via form submission to the controller method, but not working when the method is called from a jquery datatable custom button. Please go through my codes and help how to download the pdf by clicking a jquery datatable custom button.

**Controller method:**

```
public ActionResult ExportToPDF(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
    {
        List<ViewModels.SomeVM> someVMs = DBTasks.GetSomeVMs(p1, p2, p3, p4);

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Something.rpt"));
        rd.SetDataSource(someVMs);
        //rd.SetParameterValue("@p1", p1);
        //rd.SetParameterValue("@p2", p2);
        //rd.SetParameterValue("@p3", p3);
        //rd.SetParameterValue("@p4", p4);

        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Something.pdf");
    }
```

Using form submission this works fine.

**Form code in View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToPDF", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("p1", (SelectList)ViewBag.p1List, "Select P1")
    @Html.DropDownList("p2", (SelectList)ViewBag.p2List, "Select P2")
    @Html.DropDownList("p3", (SelectList)ViewBag.p3List, "Select P3")
    @Html.DropDownList("p4", (SelectList)ViewBag.p4List, "Select P4")
    <input type="submit" value="Show" id="showButton" />
}
```

But I want to do this using jquery custom button. Please help me correct the below code.

**jQuery datatable buttons configuration:**

```
// Show buttons for Export and Copy
    "buttons": [
        {
            text: 'Export',
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "/ControllerName/ExportToPDF",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "data": {
                        "p1": $("#p1").val(),
                        "p2": $("#p2").val(),
                        "p3": $("#p3").val(),
                        "p4": $("#p4").val()
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            text: 'Copy',
            titleAttr: 'Copy'
        },
]
```

Comment: what do you get in reply, can you check your entwork tab in console, check response, i can guess that its generating file but ajax don't make it download

Comment: you are absolutely right that the file was getting generated but ajax couldn't make it download. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** make a function and just call that function in button action, to avoid mess and also can call from elsewhere

```
        {
            text: 'Export',
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
               downloadpdf();
            }
```

return the url of your pdf  and then do this way

```
function downloadpdf(){
      $.ajax({
          "url": "/ControllerName/ExportToPDF",
          "type": "GET",
          "data": {// your data
           },
          xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
          },
   beforeSend: function ()
    {
         // loader start
        App.blockUI({animate: true}); 
    },
    error: function () {
        App.unblockUI();

    },
    success: function (objJson) {
            App.unblockUI();
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myfile.pdf'; //  name you want to give
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    });
}
```

**2)** there is another way by creating a form, and submiting it and then its not ajax, i used it for exporting csv and excel,

```
   $('<form>', {
        "id": "mypdf",
        "html": '<input type="hidden" name="ids" value="test" />', // any extra params
        "action": 'ExportToPDF',
        "method":'POST'
    }).appendTo(document.body).submit();

    $('#exportcsvform').remove();
```

and in your controller

```
public function actionExportcsv() {
        header('content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.pdf"');

        // code for your pdf

        exit();
    }
```

there is another way by iframe, which you can also use , by creating an iframe and open your pdf link in iframe

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, i applied your method 1. Worked like a gem!

Comment: Another thing, can you show the busy/processing animation in this custom button as long as the pdf file generation is completed in the clients end? Because, in my case the pdf generation from server side takes upto 4-5 seconds, so after clicking the export button, user may think that the button is not working at all though the file is actually being created.

Comment: you  can add loader start in beforesend of ajax, and end it in success

Comment: thank you so much dear Sunny. your suggestion works nice. i added jquery.blockUI in my project from nuget package manager and used $.blockUI/$.unblockUI instead of App.blockUI/App.unblockUI to work without any error. cheers!